# How to display image in rails with ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Rails: 6.1
Following the basic steps in the documentation of ActiveStorage I have added a avatar field for my User model and upload seems to be successful. But when I want to display @user.avatar I get a url for the image but the url seems to be 404. The image is not displayed.

Here is my image tag:

```
<img src="<%=  image_path(url_for(@user.avatar)) %>" alt="Avatar for  <%= @user.username %>">
<%= image_tag @user.avatar, class: 'user-image', alt: "Avatar for #{@user.username}" %>
```

Both of these are failing. Rendered HTML is here:

```
<img src="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--569f9d466f5dd0d4917db040f0f87d948c0af667/paddle.png?locale=en" alt="Avatar for Someone">
```

Looking at the path, paddle.png is the image I uploaded and I assume upload is okay. But why doesn't it display?

Comment: Where are you uploading the image to?  S3? Are you sure the images are set to be viewable publicly?

Comment: This is the development environment and I am not using an external service.

Comment: Ok cool, can you verify that the image is getting uploaded to the spot the URL is pointing at?

Comment: Sorry I don't know where to look for that. But I have my storage folder and it has these inside `storage/2e/gt/21djawhdrtz535fre1` and another nested folder with the same structure. So far I added 2 images and there are two. But just to try I created a new model and checked there are 3 folders now inside storage. So each image goes there.

Comment: if you open the path where the image is located in the browser, will it be displayed? Or you also get a 404 error?

Comment: I get rails' route not found page. So yes, 404.

Comment: Ohh... I just checked the tables `ActiveStorage::Attachment` and `record_id: integer` it says. I am using UUIDs for User model as ID. I think that is the problem. I will come back with update later today.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= image_tag  @user.avatar.to_s, class: "user-image" %>
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't help in my case. :(

Comment: Is this problem exists on Heroku? or local

Comment: It is happening locally.

Comment: try this: <%=image_tag url_for(@user.avatar.url) %>

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally I found what was wrong. First thing ActiveStorage is not compatible with UUID models. What's more for a given `12hefhs-342jfsoeif-senfs-senfks` UUID it takes the first consecutive digits and uses it as ID. Which is in my opinion a big issue. We don't get any error message like we do for other rails models when we try to save UUID in bigint (default id) field. To overcome this problem I had to add these migrations [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/kylefox/00c3d9ca56df78282696ef6bfef5b2f4)
Then the other problem was that I have a regex to redirect all requests to locale version of that same path. Like this:

```
get "/*path", 
    to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}", status: 302),
    constraints: { path: /(?!(#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")})\/).*/ },
    format: false
```

and this was redirecting image urls as well...
Removing this solves the problem. But introduces another one... How to redirect...